# Clarification in Eisenbud and Harris

Tags: algebraic-geometry

This is from page 59 in the text:

Let $X_{\alpha,\beta}=\text{Spec } k[x,y]/(x^2,xy,y^2,\alpha x+ \beta y)\hookrightarrow \mathbb{A}^2_k$. The subscheme $X_{\alpha,\beta}$ can be characterized as the image of the subscheme $\text{Spec }k[x]/(x^2) \subset \mathbb{A}^1_k$ under the inclusion of $\mathbb{A}^1_k$ in $\mathbb{A}^2_k$ given by $x\mapsto (\beta x, -\alpha x)$.

I do not understand this inclusion of $\mathbb{A}^1_k$ in $\mathbb{A}^2_k$. If the inclusion is given at the level of rings then it ought to be a map from $k[x,y]$ to $k[x]$, but that doesn't seem to be what's happening here; it seems as though he's mapping the generator of $k[x]$ to the ideal $(\beta x,-\alpha x)\subset k[x,y]$. My best interpretation is that he is specifying the image of the unique point $(x)$ of $\text{Spec } k[x]/(x^2)$ in $\mathbb{A}^2_k$ and that he is giving the map at the level of topological spaces (and not bothering to explicitly give the map on sheaves.)

Is this interpretation correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The map takes the maximal ideal $(x - a) \in \mathbb{A}^1_k$ to the maximal ideal $(x - \beta a, y + \alpha a) \in \mathbb{A}^2_k$. They are giving the map in terms of the point $x \in \mathbb{A}^1_k$ not the function $x \in k[x]$. Maybe "$x$" isn't the best notation for a point; that's why I used "$a$".

The dual of this map is $f(x,y) \mapsto f(\beta x, - \alpha x)$ going from $k[x,y]/(\alpha x + \beta y) \to k[x]$.